# create Q&A list with dropdownlist value/text selected as the answer vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Scenario:
I have a SQL database table with Questions.  I have another database table that stores the AnswerID, QuestionID and AnswerText.

I would like to list the questions and then show the possible answers in a drop down choice.

I am debating on trying to loop through each question in the Questions table then add a drop down list or create a data grid view with drop down options to choose from.

Must be able to then store the UserID and AnswerID to another table so that the user can view the answers to completed questions in the future.

I am just not sure what angle to take it; either continue with my current thinking of code or try to complete the task within a data grid view.

```
Function ShowQuestions()
' Pull the data for the base in this query and put in DataSet
        Dim QuestionData As System.Data.DataSet
        QuestionData = Global.ASP.Global.SQLSelect("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Inactive = 'False' ORDER BY QuestionTypeID", "Proposal")
        lblQuestionCount.Text = QuestionData.Tables(0).Rows.Count

        Dim i As Integer = 0


        QuestionHTML &= "<div id='pnlQuestionDetails_" & i & "'>"
        QuestionHTML &= "<table width='100%' align='center'>"
        QuestionHTML &= "<tr>"
        QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:right; width:15%'><h3>#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3></td>"
        QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:left; width:50%'><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Question Text</h3></td>"
        QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:center; width:35%'><h3>Question Answers</h3></td>"
        QuestionHTML &= "</tr>"

        For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In QuestionData.Tables(0).Rows

            'Dim AnswerID As Integer
            'Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT AnswerID, AnswerText FROM QuestionAnswersLink WHERE QuestionID = " & QuestionData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("QuestionID")
            'Global.ASP.Global.refresh_ddProposal(AnswerID, SQLString, ddAnswer & i)


            QuestionHTML &= "<tr>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<td colspan='3'>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<hr width='90%'>"
            QuestionHTML &= "</td></tr>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<tr>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:right'>" & i + 1 & ".&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:left'>" & QuestionData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("QuestionText") & "</td>"
            QuestionHTML &= "<td style='text-align:center'>drop down list here"
            QuestionHTML &= "</td>"
            QuestionHTML &= "</tr>"


            i = i + 1
        Next

        QuestionHTML &= "</table>"
        QuestionHTML &= "</div>"
        Return QuestionHTML
    End Function
```

In html table->tr->td I have `<%= ShowQuestions() %>`

I may be barking up the wrong tree with my original code, so any direction on what I should use is much appreciated.

Comment: DataGridView would be preferable to this.

Comment: I have been successful in changing from the above code to using a datagridview instead.  Thanks!